# Passing Class Parameter through to Widget - Undefined name error

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass a required parameter for the class through to a widget and getting Undefined name 'eventId' error. Can anyone tell me how to properly pass through the eventId to be used in the widget? Thanks

```
    class EventDetailPageFirebaseQuery extends StatefulWidget {
  const EventDetailPageFirebaseQuery({super.key,
    required this.eventId});

    final String eventId;

  @override
  _EventDetailPageFirebaseQueryState createState() => _EventDetailPageFirebaseQueryState();
}

class _EventDetailPageFirebaseQueryState extends State<EventDetailPageFirebaseQuery> {
  List dataList = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: FireStoreDataBase().getEventData(eventId: **eventId**),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return const Text(
              "Something went wrong",
            );
          }
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            dataList = snapshot.data as List;
            return buildEventScreen(event: dataList, context);
          }
          return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Undefined name 'eventId']

Comment: also create a state variable for `future`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just access it through the widget which you are building:

```
eventId: widget.eventId
```

Comment: Aw appreciate that so much. Thanks. Started learning flutter a couple of weeks ago. Everything just seems to fall into place and work but this had me stumped. Excellent.

Comment: @user237462  we are here to helps each other.